# mysql module not found

Tags: python, mysql-connector, modulenotfounderror

I have installed mysql-connector and mysql-connector-python both. Even when I run the commands on shell they work fine.

[image]

even if I try to install again it shows requirement satisfied, but when I try to run import mysql.connector through a file it throws error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your attached photo, I could see you installed the module in your "hash" directory" so try checking it there. Ensure you're running the programs in the same directory you installed the modules.

Comment: i have checked the directory where I'm running my program when tried installing module it shows requirement already satisfied.

Comment: Run your programs from that directory. You're not doing so. You're running your programs from another directory: onedrive and desktop. The right directory should be "hash" where you installed the modules.

Comment: can u tell me how to do that

Comment: thank u I resolved the issue. Instead of running it on the directory where modules are installed I copied them in the second directory where programs are stored now its working. THANKS!!!!!.

Comment: The directory is `harsh`, not hash. Plus, copying modules around isn't the proper solution for fixing the pythonpath. Both appear to be installed by pip in the same location

Comment: @Onecricketeer, you should have seen he's resolved it. Whether hash or harsh, at least he understood what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use only mysql-connector-python and you don't need both of them, first uninstall two packages and then install mysql-connector-python

Comment: As long as the import statement is correct, doesn't matter what's installed